# How to smoothly move mouse along a line in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, drawing, mouse

I have been trying to move the mouse pointer along a line over a given timespan with mixed results.  If the timespan is small enough, then each "delta" is big enough to move without too much inaccuracy caused by rounding off a PointF to a Point.

However, for longer timespans the deltas are so small that they suffer from rounding errors which causes my mouse point to not move along the original desired line.

How can I make the mouse move from one point to another in a fairly straight line without inaccuracy?

EDIT:  Perhaps these would be of use?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

[Moving the mouse along a diagonal line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751370/moving-the-mouse-along-a-diagonal-line)

Comment: Please show the code that you are using.

Comment: I'm going to look at this and see how it goes and then post some code afterwards.

http://www.morleydev.co.uk/blog/2010/11/18/generic-bresenhams-line-algorithm-in-visual-basic-net/

Comment: Rather than simply adding a delta value each time, you need to recalculate using a percentage from the starting position to the ending position.